# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

whats wrong with following query?

```
insert into table values (
(1001749039, 2010-10-29, 6, 1015583, 'B-1002-PYA-001-CM', 
 1062514, 2001422, 'y', 15.49, 2010-11-03, 'e', 2010-11-10, 3, 2010-11-10 )
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 opening parenthesis and only 1 closing one, for starters.

Answer (score 7):

1. To start with you have an extra `(`.
2. You might want to use [Table] instead of table in your query(if your table name is "Table") as "Table" it is a sql keyword.
3. And, it wouldn't throw an error but you might want to enclose your date fields in quotes i.e. use `'2010-10-29'` instead of `2010-10-29` as SQL would interpret `2010-10-29` as `1971` if not enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
insert into table values(1001749039, '2010-10-29', 6, 1015583, 'B-1002-PYA-001-CM', 1062514, 2001422, 'y', 15.49, '2010-11-03', 'e', '2010-11-10', 3, '2010-11-10' )
```